# Debugging a Qt application on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb

my Qt (QML/C++) application crashes and I can not find the reason why. I tried to output a lot of information but some signal/slot connection probably causes a crash. I spent many hours trying to find the reason but I failed.

The only good point is that I can reproduce the crash whenever I want.

Unfortunately I don't know hot to use the included GDB debugger. This is the output I got:
[image: Qt Application Crash]

How do I find from this what happened and where? I need to find at least the function, in which my application crashed.

Or what else could I try? Unfortunately I can not disable the signal/slot connections or the associated functions, because then I can not get to the point, where it crashes.

Comment: That's a huge thing you're asking ! Maybe the [Qt official tutorial on Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging.html) and [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/what_is_gdb.htm)  may help you :)

Comment: Have you compiled Muzika and Qt in debug mode? This would allow you the inspect the source code instead of disassembly code, which make debugging much easier. Another suggestion is to create a [mcve]. Your problem seems to be related to playing some media.

Comment: Muzika is my application and I compiled it in debug mode. But the crash seems to be in QtCore.dll which I downloaded as a release. Is there really no chance to find out which exact call caused the library to crash? I don't feel like compiling the whole Qt. Anyway the problem is not related to a certain media file but it happens if a file with CUE sheet reaches end of one part and then it should stop. If I stop the playback manually, it works, but if I do it programmatically (current position is at part end), then it crashes. And I can not find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has detailed documentation on how to install a debugger found here: [QtCreator Debugger](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html)

MingW does have a GDB that can be used to debug the application better. You can also use CDB to debug, just depends on your preference.

Once that is installed, you'll be able to set breakpoints and check variable information to see where your program is crashing using the Debugger view in QtCreator.

Comment: I've set up GDB and fixed Python (which was causing GDB crashes) and now it works. But still if an exception happens I can only see that it happened for example in qlist.h. But I still have no idea where in my code the problem occurred. Is it possible to trace it back which call from my code caused the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Build & Run

If you have Qt version kit like this you need to check debuggers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaY1p.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kTG6.png

You need to install MinGW and after install you will be have debugger. After install press F5 to start debuging.